# firebase.fireStore() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Just Started learning firebase using [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmTECF0JZyQ&index=3&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9itfjle0ji1xOZ2cjRGY_WB)  tutorial and i'm stuck with initialing database .These are firebase script tags placed above initialization.

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

and here's my initialization script

```
        <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "something",
        authDomain: "something",
        databaseURL: "something",
        projectId: "something",
        storageBucket: "something",
        messagingSenderId: "something"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    const db = firebase.fireStore();
    db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
    </script>
```

even this didn't work

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
```

and this is the error i got when i `console.log(db)`

> Uncaught TypeError: firebase.fireStore is not a function

Comment: Consider using a linter or a type checker to validate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) the method is called `firebase.firestore()`, not `firebase.fireStore()` (notice the capitalization).